# Resign first responder in didSelectRowAtIndexPath when using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I want to resign first responder from the currently edited textfield when a row is selected in the UITableView and a push segue is triggered inside a navigation controller. This is happening within a popover.

I've tried two things:

**(1)** I can see that the textfield is resigning the first responder while animating, but then when I go back to the view controller it takes first responder again and shows the keyboard.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

**(2)** This will prevent the restoring of the editing when going back to the view controller, but this method breaks the animation. In the end of the animation, the first view controller gets black and it jumps a little bit.

*EDIT: Just realized that this is only visible in landscape mode as it has something to do with that the keyboard animates faster than the push animation, and it gets black as soon as the keyboard is gone and the popover starts to animate to a higher height when the keyboard leaves room for it. The animation can't handle expanding the popover while animating the push animation in the navigation controller. When removing the code below and pushing and letting iOS remove the keyboard, the keyboard and push animation is taken exactly the same time and avoiding this issue. I wonder how I can make that happen myself while forcing the resignation.*

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    return indexPath;
}
```

**How can I resign first responder when changing view controller without it restoring the first responder on the text field again when navigating back?**

Comment: You can use the shouldBecomeFirstResponder delegate methods to control something becoming the first responder. Also does calling resignFirstResponder (Not sure exact wording of call) work?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't know how to identify the situation when coming back from another view controller, so shouldBecomeFirstResponder might be tricky? And resignFirstResponder gives exactly the same results as endEditing. I have two textfields on the viewcontroller, thats why I'm using endEditing to cover both.

Comment: I think the problem may be that although the view is ending editing, the actual textfields are still registered as first responder. I would suggest have a reference to the first responder. EG UItextField *firstResponder;, and set this with the parameter to the textField:DidBecomeActive call. So you always have a reference to the current first responder. Then, in viewWillDisappear, call [firstRespodner resignFirstResponder];. This should ensure that there is no first responder left. Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Your solution works exactly the same as my #2 solution. Hence the only problem is the animation glitch. I have edited my question to elaborate on what causes the glitch. If you have any pointers have to solve that problem I would be really happy :)

Comment: Sorry yeah, i didn't realise this is the same as the second one. I have posted a solution below that should ensure the keyboard is hidden before the segue occurs. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hold on a minute. So the issue is that when you perform the segue (and dismiss the view) when the view restores it has a sort of shadow of the keyboard showing. Is that it? In that case. You could try the following. when you click the tableviewcell. Do a check. like the following.

```
if(firstResponder != nil){
    //register for keyboard hide notification
    [[NSSnotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:@"UIKeyboardDidHideNotification" object:nil];. 
    [firstResponder resignFirstResponder]; 
} else {
     [self performSegue:@"yoursegueidentifier" withSender:nil];
}
```

That will only launch the segue if there is not a responder (and hence, not a keyboard). If there is a keyboard, it registers for the keyboard hide notification, and then resigns the responder. Then, in the method that responde to the keyboard hiding

```
- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
     [self performSegue:@"yoursegueidentifier" withSender:nil];
 }
```

This should only perform the segue when the keyboard has hidden, so it should resolve the animation issue. You may need to modify your storyboard to have the segue launch from the view controller and not from the cell's button, I'm not sure about how your architecture is. let me know if this works or not.